# How do i send keys using a global keyboard hook?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, hook, inject

I'm trying to send keys to an application which does not respond to any of the API's that I have so far used (SendInput(), PostMessage(), SendMessage() and others). However, i tested Windows' On-Screen Keyboard Utility and pressed the keys i needed and the application received these keys easily.

If i understand correctly the keyboard utility uses global keyboard hooks to send the keys, so I'm interested i how i could do so as well. I have tried finding examples of how this can be done on google but have come up with no results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hooks are used to intercept the events, not to send new event. So what you're asking is impossible with hooks. `SendInput` is the way to go. probably you did something wrong, so it'll be better if you post your code that doesn't work and debug what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I was sending keys to a DirectX application. Turns out i had to send DirectX scan codes instead of regular VK_KEY's.

A list of scan codes can be found at: http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

Using these with SendInput() and everything worked great.

Thanks for the help also.

Cheers.